# Why logging works in a single call but not from main function?

Tags: python, logging

I have a function called `setup_logger()` that sets up the logging system for my application, and it's located in the `controllers.py` file.
It works pretty well. But sometimes the logging is not being called when I run the functions from `main.py` (I'm using `asyncio` for some functions).

When I call my function `get_browser()` itself, the `logging` works and sends the message to `StreamHandler` and `FileHandler` as it is supposed to do.
But when I call this same function `get_browser()` from my file `main.py`, the logging doesn't do anything.

I'd like to know what could be stopping the logging function from being called, if it's the `asyncio` or something else.

My repo: https://github.com/guimatheus92/Bot_BombCrypto

My project:

```
└── Project
    ├── main.py         # setup our app
    ├── controllers.py  # this file contains setup_logger() and get_browser()
```

`get_browser()` function:

```
def get_browser():
    logger = setup_logger(telegram_integration=True)
    logger.info("Profiles selected: ...")

    applications = []
    website_browser = []

    return applications, website_browser
```

`setup_logger()` function:

```
def setup_logger(telegram_integration=False, bot_name=''):
    if bot_name != '':
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s | Function: %(funcName)s | %(asctime)s: Bot (' + str(bot_name) + '):  %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    else:
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s | Function: %(funcName)s | %(asctime)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')

    level = logging.INFO

    consolehandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    consolehandler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = logging.getLogger('logs')
    if logger.hasHandlers():
        # Logger is already configured, remove all handlers
        logger.handlers = []
    else:
        logger.setLevel(level)
        logger.addHandler(consolehandler)

    return logger
```

In the `main.py` I'm just calling:

```
applications, website_browser = get_browser()
```

```py
async def main():
    logger = setup_logger(telegram_integration=True)

    logger.info('------------------- New Execution ----------------\n')
    logger.info('Starting Bot..... Bot started!')

    applications, website_browser = get_browser()
    logger.info('Number of accounts that the bot will run: %s' % (len(applications)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:                
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.create_task(main())
        loop.run_forever()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: " + str(e))
        exit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `main()` calls `setup_logger()` twice:

   - `main()` → `setup_logger()`
   - `main()` → `get_browser()` → `setup_logger()`
2. `setup_logger` removes all handlers if already configured and configures only if it was not:

```py
def setup_logger(telegram_integration=False, bot_name=''):
    # Prepare handlers
    # ...

    logger = logging.getLogger('logs')
    if logger.hasHandlers():
        # Logger is already configured, remove all handlers
        logger.handlers = []
    else:
        logger.setLevel(level)
        logger.addHandler(consolehandler)
```

## Solution

Move the configuration out of the `else` block:

```py
def setup_logger(telegram_integration=False, bot_name=''):
    # Prepare handlers
    # ...

    logger = logging.getLogger('logs')
    if logger.hasHandlers():
        # Logger is already configured, remove all handlers
        logger.handlers = []
    
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(consolehandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, logging facilities should only be configured once unless you can't afford a cold reload of your application.

Have you considered using the standard `logging.config.dictConfig` instead of all your `setup_logger`? Simply craft the dict config dynamically with whatever parameterization you need and issue the configuration **once**, even before starting the event loop. Later, get the configured logger directly with `logging.getLogger`

I think this would aid you organising your code.

```py
class TelegramHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, bot_name=''):
        super().__init__()
        self.bot_name = bot_name

    def emit(self, record):
        message = self.format(record)
        send_telegram_msg(message, self.bot_name)


def get_logging_cfg(telegram_integration=False, bot_name=''):
    return {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'formatters': {
            'default': {
                'format':
                    '%(levelname)s | Function: %(funcName)s | %(asctime)s: Bot (' + str(bot_name) + '):  %(message)s'
                    if bot_name else
                    '%(levelname)s | Function: %(funcName)s | %(asctime)s: %(message)s',
                'datefmt': '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'file': {
                'formatter': 'default',
                'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
                'filename': os.path.join(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve(), 'logs', 'myapp.log'),
                'when': 'D',
            },
            'telegram': {
                'formatter': 'default',
                'class': 'import.path.to.you.module.TelegramHandler',
                'bot_name': bot_name,
            },
            'null': {
                'formatter': 'default',
                'class': 'logging.handlers.NullHandler',
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            'logs': {
                'handlers':
                    (['file'] if create_logfiles else [])
                    + (['telegram'] if telegram_integration and telegram_token else [])
            }
        },
        'root': {
            # consider something else, for the sake of the logging happening beyond your own code
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
    }


async def main():
    logger = logging.getLogger('logs')
    logger.info('start')
    applications, website_browser = get_browser()
    # ...


def get_browser():
    logger = logging.getLogger('logs')
    logger.info('whatever')
    # ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.config.dictConfig(
        get_logging_cfg(
            telegram_integration=True,
            bot_name='foo',
        )
    )
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(main())
    loop.run_forever()
```

Bonus: use [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) instead of all that manual path crafting.

Python's logging is a beautiful library, you'll be happier if you read its [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) [thoroughly](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial)